# node JS expreess UNDEFIED CALL BACK

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, ejs

I am working on a personal project and I do not have much experience with nodeJS, the idea is to bring a JSON that has remotely taken some data and generate some statistics, I am doing some tests before starting fully in the project and I am having problems with the callback.

the server.js works correctly,

my module is the following:

```js
const extjson = require('remote-json');

//---------------------API CONFIG--------------------------
//apikey
const apikey ="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

function get_sum_id(sumname){
  const urlsumbySumName = "https://la2.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/" + sumname + "?api_key=" + apikey;
  var id;
  extjson(urlsumbySumName).get((err, res, body)=> {
    id = body.id;
    });
  return id;
}
module.exports = {get_sum_id

  };
```

and the routes.js is the following:

```js
const riot = require('./rapi.js');
const express = require('express');

//---------------------------------------------------------

const router = express.Router();
//Jtask -- task remote json
//const Task = require('../models/Task'); // taskdb

router.get('/',async (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});

router.post('/profile', (req,res)=>{
  const sum = req.body.summoners; 
  console.log(riot.get_sum_id(sum));

  res.render('profile',{sum});
});
module.exports = router;
```

I want to show that id by console and it returns undefined, the idea is to pass that value to the render below to have it available in an EJS document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module make an asynchronous call to another server with `remote-json`. It means that the callback will be called only after the request to this other server. So, this line `return id;` is read before this line `id = body.id;`.

One way to fix that is to provide the callback from the place where you call your module function.

Based on your code you could do something like that :

```
// module.js
const extjson  = require('remote-json');

const apikey ="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

function get_sum_id (sumname, callback) {
  const urlsumbySumName = "https://la2.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/" + sumname + "?api_key=" + apikey;
  extjson(urlsumbySumName).get(callback);
}

module.exports = { get_sum_id };

// app.js
const riot = require('./rapi.js');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/profile', function(req, res, next) {
  riot.get_sum_id(req.body.summoners, function (err, resp, body) {
    console.log(body);
    res.json(body); // Response here
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Now, requests to your server will be in pending until your callback close it with `res.json(body);`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much I am working, now I understand much better how the asynchronous functions work. I leave here the complete solution to my problem in case someone needs it in the future:

```
//rapi.js

    const extjson = require ('remote-json');

    //---------------------API CONFIG--------------------------
    //apikey
    const apikey ="RGAPI-77f658f1-ff2b-40e7-a74c-47f7510c8dac";
    //trayendo los datos desde riot


    function  get_sum_id(sumname, callback){
      const urlsumbySumName = "https://la2.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/" + sumname + "?api_key=" + apikey;
      extjson(urlsumbySumName).get(callback)
      }

    module.exports = { get_sum_id };

//routesapp.js
const riot = require('./rapi.js');
const express = require('express');
//---------------------------------------------------------
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/',async (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});

router.post('/profile', (req, res, next)=>{
  const sum = req.body.summoners;

  riot.get_sum_id(sum,function (err, resp, body){
    console.log(body.id);
    //responces....
    res.render('profile',{sum, id: body.id})
  });

});
module.exports = router;
```

TNX very much!